# Rasterio to Postgis without save file in disk

Tags: python, postgis, rasterio

Does anyone know how to upload a rasterio object to PostGIS using Python?

I have checked: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io

Sadly, there is not too much info about PostGIS. I know it can use GDAL drivers, but seems GDAL is independent about the raster creation, is not like necessary the raster will inherit the properties, and maybe I should set every property in the raster creation.

There is the option to save the file as GeoTiff, and then use raster2pgsql, but I want to avoid that method, my main reason is about the actual drives, SSD are pretty fast, but has a limited number of read/write cycles, doing that all the time can really eat the disk. My second reason is I would like to avoid depends on the system that much, so avoid system scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Rasterio doesn't appear to be set up to do everything in-memory. There is some mumbles about the GDAL VSI support in the manual, but the section is incomplete. Depending on what you're doing, it is possible to convert to PostGIS Raster format and upload to a PostgreSQL server without an intermediary via a pipe (assuming you are on Linux/Unix/BSD): `raster2pgsql ... | psql -U user -d database`.

Also, don't worry about wearing out your SSD. It has millions of write cycles and write leveling; it would take concerted effort (i.e., filling the entire device with random data in a loop for months) to wear down the cells to a point where the device is unusable. If you're having troubles with eating SSDs, then stop buying the cheap ones.

If using physical storage for temp space is a major difficulty, and you have sufficient RAM, then create a RAM disk and put the temp data there.

Comment: Hi, in case I use ```raster2pgsql``` I still need to save the file...., if you know how to do it I would appreciate a reference link. I work with some heavy loads, so, months of intense work on the SSD is something I want to avoid, maybe would be different if is years of heavy workload. Use the ram as a disk, in python I found ```SpooledTemporaryFile``` from ```tempfile``` sadly it does not allows have a filename, is needed for ```raster2pgsql```. if there is other reference link to can use a named file in memory would be great.

Comment: Setting up a RAM disk is more a [sf] question.

Comment: The idea is can upload the raster of rasterio to postgis from python D: avoid go out of it.